# UWP App using MVVM: Registration of feature view on main view

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, feature-driven

I am new to c# and uwp apps. And this is my first try with MVVM.
I have the following program design and go according to the schema of the FDD. 
[MVVM App-Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pYAq.png)

I would like to achieve:

- Registration of the ViewFeature.xaml on ViewMain.xaml
- communication between features.

I have the following simple Approach: Add the ViewFeature.xaml to ViewMain.xaml by Code, which unfortunately does not work at the moment.

- View Registration:

MainView.xaml

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewModels="using:Client.ViewModel"
x:Class="Client.View.ViewMain"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="FeatureLeft"      Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <StackPanel Name="FeatureCenter"    Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <StackPanel Name="FeatureRight"     Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

ViewMain.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class ViewMain : Page
{

    public ViewModelMain viewModelMain;

    public ViewMain()
    {           
        this.InitializeComponent();
        viewModelMain = new ViewModelMain();
        viewModelMain.RegisterFeatures(this);        
    }
}
```

ViewModelMain.cs

```
public class ViewModelMain: NotificationBase
{
    public ModelMain model;
    public ViewModelMain()
    {
        model = new ModelMain();
        _Features = model.LoadFeatures();
    }

    public void RegisterFeatures(Page p)
    {
        foreach (var feature in _Features)
        {
            feature.AddToView(p);
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<IViewFeature> _Features = new ObservableCollection<IViewFeature>();
    public ObservableCollection<IViewFeature> Features {
        get { return _Features; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Features, value); }
    }

}
```

ModelMain.cs

```
public class ModelMain
{

    public ObservableCollection<IViewFeature> FeatureList;


    public ObservableCollection<IViewFeature> LoadFeatures()
    {
        FeatureList = new ObservableCollection<IViewFeature>();
        IViewFeature galleryFeature = new Gallery.View.ViewGallery();
        FeatureList.Add(galleryFeature);

        return FeatureList;
    }

}
```

Each Feature knows his own position on the ViewMain.xml and implements in the ViewFeaure.xaml.cs the following method to register its own ViewFeature.xaml on the ViewMain.xaml

```
public void AddToView( Page p)
    {
        StackPanel target = (StackPanel)p.FindName("FeatureLeft");
        target.Children.Add(this);
    }
```

Any professional approach or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What exactly is not working?

Comment: @user1777136 The main view is blank and there is no error message. There should be a button, which opens the detail view of an image gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line.

```
target.Children.Add(this);
```

should be

```
target.Children.Add(this as UIElement);
```

However, I would still want to know how a professional approach to feature-based applications might look in the context of feature-driven development (FDD).

Comment: Your code looks reasonable. What I would shy away from is to "hard code" the `StackPanel` inside the `AddToView` method. The binding mechanism can get you out of this. MVVM relies heavily on bindings to decouple code from the view. So e.g. `<StackPanel Name="FeatureLeft"      Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Features}" />` would allow you to remove the entire `RegisterFeatures` and `AddToView` methods.